# Jenkins Artifactory plugin: a script in "Declarative Pipeline Syntax" – how to bypass the configured proxy?

Tags: artifactory

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins

This article attempts to describe all the details as well for "*Declarative Pipeline Syntax*" as for "*Scripted Pipeline Syntax*".
but for "*Declarative …*" it does not describe how to bypass the proxy whereas for "*Scripted …*" it does: "`server.bypassProxy = true`".

So how would I specify bypassing the proxy in a Jenkins pipeline script with "*Declarative Pipeline Syntax*"?

Answer (score 3):

In `rtServer` add `bypassProxy: true`:

```
rtServer (
    id: "Artifactory-1",
    url: "http://my-artifactory-domain/artifactory",
    username: "user",
    password: "password",
    bypassProxy: true
)
```

Comment: I had tried exactly that (although it is not documented), before I posted the issue. I was quite disappointed then, that id did not work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the error that you receives? I test 'bypassProxy: true
' on my machine and it worked. This line should make it work:
https://github.com/jfrog/jenkins-artifactory-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfrog/hudson/pipeline/declarative/steps/CreateServerStep.java#L55

Comment: Can you open an issue here with all of the relevant details?
https://github.com/jfrog/jenkins-artifactory-plugin/issues

Comment: It works the way you described it above. There were other reasons, why I wasn't able to reach the Artifactory server. Now that they are fixed, everything is fine. Thanks a lot for your advise!

Comment: I am going to remove my comment "I had tried …" in order to clean this thread up – supposing you agree to that.